# nginx regex configuration for 404 images

Tags: nginx, regex

I have dynamic link series like below;

http://example.com/users/1871233/18712443_cover.jpg

Only static thing is on that link is example.com/users and _cover.I want to make that ; when requested is not found return a jpg

```
location ~ ^\/users\/(.*)\/(.*)_cover.*(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
        error_page 404 /deff_images/empty-cover-jpg.jpg;
}
```

I did smt like above but not worked .

What can i do for that ? 
So thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using extra characters in the regex. Try this:

```
location ~^/users/[0-9]+/[0-9]+_cover\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
    error_page 404 /deff_images/empty-cover-jpg.jpg;
}
```

Comment: So thanks , but it not working propery . It gaves already 404 not found but no image

Comment: I had a typo in the filename. If that wasn't the problem, then check that your `server` block's `root` directive is defined properly so that the file is accessible at `$document_root/deff_images/empty-cover-jpg.jpg`